# How to route and resolve pages in Kentico

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc, kentico-api

I am creating a Kentico website and have been through the tutorial and reading up on the handling links for Kentico MVC. From what I understand, Kentico is encouraging developers to use the standard MVC routing to map pages to controllers.

This is fine for sections of the site, or if you only have a few pages, but the site I am developing has a large content structure and lots of top level pages.

It seems unreasonable to have to create a custom route in the `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` for every top level page. Is there are better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's also another great post on the subject by Sean Wright. https://dev.to/seangwright/kentico-12-design-patterns-part-10-mvc-routing-with-nodealiaspath-22l3

I would recommend checking this out as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Dynamic Routing module has been published on NuGet.

for the "Mother" admin
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicRouting.Kentico/

For the MVC
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicRouting.Kentico.MVC/

Documentation and source code on Github
https://github.com/KenticoDevTrev/DynamicRouting